# When Insertdata, adddata and delete data the emulator couldn't open the application

Tags: java, android, sqlite

MainActivity.java

android studio do not show any error in this code, but maybe it still have some problem.

```
package com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

static final String DB_NAME="HotlineDB";
static final String TB_NAME="hotlist";
static final  int MAX=8;
static final String[] FROM = new String[] {"name" , "phone" , "list"};
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cur;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
EditText etName, etPhone , etList;
Button btInsert , btUpdate , btDelete;
ListView lv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etPhone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    etList=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etList);
    btInsert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btInsert);
    btUpdate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btUpdate);
    btDelete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btDelete);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME , Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String createTable= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_NAME + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "name VARCHAR(32), " +
            "phone VARCHAR(16) " +
            "list VARCHAR(100))";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
    cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TB_NAME, null);
    if (cur.getCount()==0) {
        addData("姓名" , "0932828387", "點餐資訊");
    }
    adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.item, cur, FROM, new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.phone, R.id.list}, 0);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    requery();
}

private void addData(String name, String phone, String list) {
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues(3);
    cv.put(FROM[0], name);
    cv.put(FROM[1], phone);
    cv.put(FROM[2], list);

    db.insert(TB_NAME, null, cv);
}

private void update(String name, String phone, String list, int id) {
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues(3);
    cv.put(FROM[0], name);
    cv.put(FROM[1], phone);
    cv.put(FROM[2], list);

    db.update(TB_NAME, cv, "_id=" + id, null);
}

private void requery() {
    cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TB_NAME, null);
    adapter.changeCursor(cur);
    if (cur.getCount()==MAX)
        btInsert.setEnabled(false);
    else
        btInsert.setEnabled(true);
    btUpdate.setEnabled(false);
    btDelete.setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    cur.moveToPosition(position);

    etName.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(FROM[0])));
    etPhone.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(FROM[1])));
    etList.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(FROM[2])));

    btUpdate.setEnabled(true);
    btDelete.setEnabled(true);
}

public void onInsertUpdate(View v) {
    String nameStr=etName.getText().toString().trim();
    String phoneStr=etPhone.getText().toString().trim();
    String listStr=etList.getText().toString().trim();
    if (nameStr.length()==0 || phoneStr.length()==0 || listStr.length()==0) return;

    if (v.getId()==R.id.btUpdate)
        update(nameStr, phoneStr, listStr, cur.getInt(0));
    else
        addData(nameStr, phoneStr, listStr);
    requery();
}
        public void onDelete(View v) {
            db.delete(TB_NAME, "_id="+cur.getInt(0), null);
        requery();
        }




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_weight="0.61" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.11">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="姓名:"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.04">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="電話:"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etPhone"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="點餐資料:"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etList"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.02">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="新增"
            android:id="@+id/btInsert"
            android:onClick="onInsertUpdate" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="修改"
            android:id="@+id/btUpdate"
            android:onClick="onInsertUpdate" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="刪除"
            android:id="@+id/btDelete"
            android:onClick="onDelete" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button4" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#07a"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="232dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:textColor="#840"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="#480" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat

```
12-26 04:42:17.897      595-622/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{34fea538 u0 com.android.music/.MediaPlaybackService}
    --------- beginning of main
12-26 04:42:23.800      595-672/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ CMD_START_SCAN : connected mode and no configuration
12-26 04:42:26.636      595-622/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{3de74a14 u0 com.android.calendar/.alerts.InitAlarmsService}
12-26 04:42:29.201    1773-1773/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
12-26 04:42:29.202    1773-1773/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is OFF
12-26 04:42:29.227    1773-1773/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-26 04:42:29.227    1773-1773/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-26 04:42:29.240    1773-1773/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
12-26 04:42:29.243     595-1075/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline appid=10062 user=0: from pid 1773
12-26 04:42:29.244    1773-1773/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-26 04:42:29.550    1789-1789/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
12-26 04:42:29.552    1789-1789/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is OFF
12-26 04:42:29.576    1789-1789/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-26 04:42:29.576    1789-1789/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-26 04:42:29.588    1789-1789/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
12-26 04:42:29.594      595-954/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline/.MainActivity} from uid 0 on display 0
12-26 04:42:29.594      595-954/? V/WindowManager﹕ addAppToken: AppWindowToken{2df54b5e token=Token{255bac99 ActivityRecord{19a431e0 u0 com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline/.MainActivity t14}}} to stack=1 task=14 at 0
12-26 04:42:29.602    1789-1789/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-26 04:42:29.607      595-633/? V/WindowManager﹕ Adding window Window{b1450a4 u0 Starting com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline} at 2 of 7 (after Window{28411ca3 u0 com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher})
12-26 04:42:29.614    1802-1802/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-26 04:42:29.621      595-829/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc 1802:com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline/u0a62 for activity com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline/.MainActivity
12-26 04:42:29.752    1802-1802/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "list": syntax error
12-26 04:42:29.752    1802-1802/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
12-26 04:42:29.753    1802-1802/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline, PID: 1802
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline/com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "list": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotlist(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(32), phone VARCHAR(16) list VARCHAR(100))
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "list": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotlist(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(32), phone VARCHAR(16) list VARCHAR(100))
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
            at com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
12-26 04:42:29.757      595-682/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline/.MainActivity
12-26 04:42:29.760      613-616/? D/PermissionCache﹕ checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for uid=1000 => granted (220 us)
12-26 04:42:29.788      613-613/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 613: eglCreateSyncKHR(1209): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
12-26 04:42:29.948     595-1426/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-26 04:42:29.985     595-1426/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-26 04:42:29.985     595-1426/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe14cdbc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-26 04:42:30.190     595-1426/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-26 04:42:30.190     595-1426/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe14cdbc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-26 04:42:30.652      595-622/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{19a431e0 u0 com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline/.MainActivity t14 f}
12-26 04:42:30.722     926-1132/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-26 04:42:30.722     926-1132/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeed44a20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-26 04:42:30.837      595-954/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 1584:com.svox.pico/u0a49 (adj 15): empty #17
12-26 04:42:31.368     926-1132/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
12-26 04:42:31.666      716-716/? W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
12-26 04:42:31.666      716-716/? W/PackageManager﹕ Failure retrieving resources for com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline: Resource ID #0x0
12-26 04:42:40.874      595-622/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{19a431e0 u0 com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline/.MainActivity t14 f}
12-26 04:42:41.637    1367-1703/? D/InitAlarmsService﹕ Clearing and rescheduling alarms.
12-26 04:42:41.673      595-991/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 993:android.process.acore/u0a2 (adj 15): empty #17
12-26 04:42:43.814      595-672/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ CMD_START_SCAN : connected mode and no configuration
12-26 04:42:44.380      595-695/? D/TaskPersister﹕ removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=14_task.xml
12-26 04:42:44.380      595-695/? D/TaskPersister﹕ removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=14_task_thumbnail.png
12-26 04:43:03.817      595-672/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ CMD_START_SCAN : connected mode and no configuration
12-26 04:43:05.127      595-954/? I/MediaFocusControl﹕ AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@1b9660bccom.android.music.MediaPlaybackService$3@1de8a845
12-26 04:43:05.128    1485-1485/? V/MusicFXControlPanelReceiver﹕ onReceive
12-26 04:43:05.128    1485-1485/? V/MusicFXControlPanelReceiver﹕ Action: android.media.action.CLOSE_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
12-26 04:43:05.128    1485-1485/? V/MusicFXControlPanelReceiver﹕ Package name: com.android.music
12-26 04:43:05.128    1485-1485/? V/MusicFXControlPanelReceiver﹕ Audio session: 8
12-26 04:43:05.128    1485-1485/? V/MusicFXControlPanelEffect﹕ closeSession(android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@90c88c0, com.android.music, 8)
12-26 04:43:05.130      595-947/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 1183:com.android.music/u0a42 (adj 15): empty #17
12-26 04:43:05.132      209-209/? E/lowmemorykiller﹕ Error writing /proc/1183/oom_score_adj; errno=22
12-26 04:43:10.150      595-679/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
12-26 04:43:10.163    1802-1802/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1802 SIG: 9
12-26 04:43:10.185      595-954/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.example.brian.ch15_myhotline (pid 1802) has died
12-26 04:43:10.217     595-1426/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xda83df80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xda8ff9e0
12-26 04:43:10.221      595-829/? W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@10556917 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@1f3c93d2
12-26 04:43:23.827      595-672/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ CMD_START_SCAN : connected mode and no configuration
```

It seems like did not have any error in my code but I sill can't open it. Hope someone can help me solve this problem thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Error in creating table :

Check this code  :

```
 static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
            "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text); ";
```